# Flutter cache data with Floor on mobile but want to build for web as well

Tags: flutter, floor

I want to suport both android and web.

However I use Floor to cache data and it is not supported on web. So I want to make the database calls only on android, I don't want to cache the data on web. I want to ignore these lines on web.

Can I do this somehow?

```
void loadNews() async {
    emit(Loading());
    await newsCacheRepository.init();  //because of this line on web the data doesn't appear
    var articles = await newsCacheRepository.getArticles();
    emit(Loaded(articles));
    refreshNews();
  }

  Future<void> refreshNews() async {
    var articles = await newsNetworkRepository.getArticles();
    emit(Loaded(articles));
    newsCacheRepository.cacheArticles(articles);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hive which supports web too. Or you can always check for platform:

```
if(!kIsWeb){
 // Your code that doesn't support web
 }
```

But to be safe side, you can wrap the code on a try-catch block.

But I prefer using Hive which supports web.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Maybe I'll check Hive in the future :)